# Why is my code not printing the way i want

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have a macro button "PRINT" so that once information is filled in the operator can print sequentially numbered cards.  I need to print TWO cards for each sequential number but it only prints one.  What am I missing?

```
Sub printjob()
            'DEFINE VARIABLES
Dim card1tote As Range
Dim printloop As Integer
Dim endloop As Integer
Set card1tote = Range("H22")
endloop = Range("G28").Value
endtote = Range("S16").Value
            'BEGIN PRINT LOOP
For printloop = 1 To endloop
            'SET CARD1TOTE NUMBER
If printloop = 1 Then
    card1tote.Value = card1tote.Value + Range("S14").Value
   Else
    card1tote.Value = card1tote.Value + 1
End If
            'WRITE TOTE NUMBER TO CARD1TOTE CELL
Set card1tote = Range("H22")
            'PRINT CARDS
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
            'NEXT CYCLE/END PRINT LOOP
Next printloop
            'SET TOTE NUMBER CELLS TO ZERO
card1tote.Value = 0
            'END SUBROUTINE
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=2`?

Comment: GSerg, thank you but it still only prints one.

Comment: after setting endloop, add a MsgBox("endloop=" & endloop) just to validate what is being used.